# fsevent: running worker failed: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Цикл ужаса после обновления macOS продолжается.

На сей раз ошибка возникает при запуске задачи. В чем проблема на этот раз?

```
E, [2017-01-29T16:38:19.274520 #65922] ERROR -- : fsevent: running worker failed: Resource temporarily unavailable - /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/bin/fsevent_watch:/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `popen'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `open_pipe'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:37:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add' called from: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:67:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
E, [2017-01-29T16:38:19.279265 #65922] ERROR -- : fsevent: running worker failed: Resource temporarily unavailable - /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/bin/fsevent_watch:/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `popen'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `open_pipe'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:37:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add' called from: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:67:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
E, [2017-01-29T16:38:19.279673 #65922] ERROR -- : fsevent: running worker failed: Resource temporarily unavailable - /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/bin/fsevent_watch:/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `popen'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `open_pipe'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:37:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add' called from: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:67:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
E, [2017-01-29T16:38:19.279801 #65922] ERROR -- : fsevent: running worker failed: Resource temporarily unavailable - /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/bin/fsevent_watch:/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `popen'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `open_pipe'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:37:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add' called from: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:67:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
E, [2017-01-29T16:38:19.279912 #65922] ERROR -- : fsevent: running worker failed: Resource temporarily unavailable - /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/bin/fsevent_watch:/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `popen'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `open_pipe'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:37:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add' called from: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:67:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
E, [2017-01-29T16:38:19.280002 #65922] ERROR -- : fsevent: running worker failed: Resource temporarily unavailable - /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/bin/fsevent_watch:/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `popen'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `open_pipe'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:37:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add' called from: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:67:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
E, [2017-01-29T16:38:19.280083 #65922] ERROR -- : fsevent: running worker failed: Resource temporarily unavailable - /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/bin/fsevent_watch:/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `popen'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `open_pipe'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:37:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add' called from: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:67:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
E, [2017-01-29T16:38:19.280176 #65922] ERROR -- : fsevent: running worker failed: Resource temporarily unavailable - /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/bin/fsevent_watch:/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `popen'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `open_pipe'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:37:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add' called from: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:67:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
E, [2017-01-29T16:38:19.280294 #65922] ERROR -- : fsevent: running worker failed: Resource temporarily unavailable - /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/bin/fsevent_watch:/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `popen'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:106:in `open_pipe'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.9.8/lib/rb-fsevent/fsevent.rb:37:in `run'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:68:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add' called from: /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:67:in `_run_worker'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/darwin.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in _run_workers_in_background'
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/internals/thread_pool.rb:6:in `block in add'
```

Comment: [В настройках OS X?](http://blog.ghostinthemachines.com/2010/01/19/mac-os-x-fork-resource-temporarily-unavailable/)

Comment: @D-side спасибо Apple за столь охринительный апдейт OS :) Никогда проблем не было, пока 2 дня назад система не решила самостоятельно уйти в обновление...